# Basic installer not showing program in Start menu

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have made a deployment project for my very simple .Net 4.0 C# Winforms app
Yet when I install it, I do not see the program on the start menu.  Tested on my 64-bit Win7 desktop and my 32-bit XP Laptop.

I have done this in the past and it worked fine.  What crazy default value setting am I missing?

Thank you

Daniel

Comment: It's been my experience that you need to remember to add your company and product name to the installer package's properties. These details are the basis for which folder the application is installed to (unless you've customized additional folder paths to place files through the install wizard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the basic installer (Windows Installer) provided in Visual Studio you have to add an actual shortcut to "the primary output" to your desktop and/or Startmenu. Afaik it is not added automatically.

Comment: Right-click + Create shortcut.

Comment: Thakn you.  I needed to add a Company folder under "Users programs Menu", then create a shortcut from the Application Folder's Primary output, then rename that shortcut and put it under the company folder the users programs menu folder.   Now it looks right, but kind of annoying that this was not default behavoir.

Comment: @Daniel, I do think @Hans has a quicker way of doing it. I'm not able to try it now.